# Keeping synced keychains on same Mac

Tags: icloud, keychain

Apparently Chrome will never support iCloud keychain and will use the default keychain because Apple only allows access to the former if the app is distributed through the App Store (see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=312105)

So I was wondering whether there's an app or script that automatically syncs between different local keychains (thereby working around the limitation imposed by Apple.)

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't actually suggest an app to sync the local keychains, I provide you with an alternative solution: you can sync the passwords between the different users in your Mac if you sync Chrome with the same Google account in both users:

- [Why sign in to Chrome - Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165139?hl=en)

Comment: Well, the point is that I don't want to sync across accounts. I want to sync the passwords in the iCloud Keychain with the default one, used among other, by Chrome.

Comment: Oh, then this solution does not work, sorry :-(